# How to get Keyboard isShowing or not Android

Tags: android, keyboard, virtual

I want to get state of android virtual keyboard. How can i know virtual keyboard is open or closed?

I want to use this information in onBackPressed() event.

I have already tried below code but cant get solution.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            Log.i("isAcceptingText","..."+inputManager.isAcceptingText());
            Log.i("isActive","..."+ inputManager.isActive());
```

When keyboard is open it does not run "Log" messages.

Comment: see this post maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android

Answer (score 1):

This method use onMeasure(). It checks if activity screen is smaller.

[How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)